# Where do I create CakePHP 3 reusable functionality that can be accessed by controllers and shells?

Tags: shell, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a CakePHP 3 application in which I want to create a wrapper for an external API. I'd like to use this wrapper in both a controller and also inside a shell that I will call using a cron job. I can't quite figure out where I would place this class, or indeed which type of class (Component, Model etc.) I should use. In `CakePHP 2` I recall this type of thing going in the `lib` directory.

Components are only specifically for Controllers, so are no good in a shell. So, what kind of class should I create and where should I place it in my directory structure so it's accessible and reusable?

**Bonus points:** In the near future, I'd like to make this class reusable by putting it in our custom `Plugin` application, so I'd like to know how to do that too if possible (I suspect this will be answered if we figure out the first bit).

Comment: You should create your wrapper outside of CakePHP, put it in a `vendor/MyWrapper` directory (equivalent to the old `lib`) and then either create a component/model (depending on the API is) that will use it or simply import your class into your CakePHP controllers.

Comment: Thanks @Holt. Are you suggesting that we don't create a CakePHP-specific class, but rather just a generic PHP class that does this and import it where we need it?

Comment: Yes, if you do not need to use any CakePHP specific stuff in your wrapper, create a standard PHP class. Lots of online APIs already provide PHP class to communicate with them.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @Holt